# Windows Batch File To Execute SQL Scripts In Ascending Order Of Folder Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

Is there a way to write windows batch file that will execute SQL Scripts Ascending Order Of Folder Name (Example Shown Below) and Execute SQL Script File in Numeric Order of Preceding File Name (Eg: In 1. Folder -> 1. SQL, 2.SQL, 3. SQL).

Eg:

1. Folderx

   1. scX.sql
   2. scY.sql
   3. scZ.sql
      more..
2. Foldery

   1. scA.sql
   2. spB.sql
   3. spC.sql
      more...
3. Folderz

   1. vwV.sql
   2. vwG.sql
      more...

So basically is there a way to execute scripts by ascending order of folder name and file name

Comment: _Is there a way to write windows batch file that [...]_ Yes there is. I recommend reading the documentation for the command shell environment, or Power Shell, which might be a better option. When you run into trouble, come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: how do you execute your scripts? sql.exe ? how do you pass the file to the executable?

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to form a list of files in the order we need. And then for each file start [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). To get a list in this order you can use `DIR` Windows command. For example:

```
dir "c:\SQL_SCRIPTS" /S /B /A-D /ON
```

This command will show all files from `"c:\SQL_SCRIPTS"` folder with subfolders (`/S`). It will show only file names without additional info (dates, attributes,...) (`/B`) and without folders list (`/A-D`). And we need alphabetic name order (`/ON`).

Now we need to make a loop for this list and for each line run a SQLCMD command so we will use `FOR` Windows command.

This script will generate `cmd.sql` file to execute all scripts from "c:\SQL_SCRIPTS" folder:

```
FOR /f "Delims=" %%I in ('dir "c:\SQL_SCRIPTS" /S /B /A-D /ON') DO echo sqlcmd -U myLogin -P myPassword -S MyServerName -d MyDatabaseName -i "%%I" >>cmd.sql
```

Or another way - run each command in loop at once without generating `cmd.sql` file:

```
FOR /f "Delims=" %%I in ('dir "c:\SQL_SCRIPTS" /S /B /A-D /ON') DO sqlcmd -U myLogin -P myPassword -S MyServerName -d MyDatabaseName -i "%%I"
```

Comment: This will fail if there are more than 9 files inside a folder. `2. sp.sql` is greater than `10. sp.sql`

Comment: @MCND  Yes your're right. In this case topic starter can name script files using fixed number format: 001,002,003,....

Comment: Thank you very very much, i will try this and update you guys with results